# Trouble with SQL syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax

Here is my code.. I'm trying to get it to validate against the database.

pass/user = Admin

```
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void main_B_Signup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegWindow rWindow = new RegWindow();
        rWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void main_B_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //connect to the database
        SqlConnection loginConn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;"+ "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "database=Production; " + "connection timeout=30");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select *from User where Username=' " + this.Main_T_Username.Text + " ' and Password=' " + this.Main_T_Password.Text + " ' ;", loginConn);
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select *from User where Username='@Username' and Password='@Password';", loginConn);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", this.Main_T_Username.Text));
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Password", this.Main_T_Password.Text));

        loginConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string username = null;

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    username = rdr["Username"].ToString();
                }

                loginConn.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Well done!");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WrongPass!");
                loginConn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

but the error I get is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

But the table is called `User` and there are columns `Username` and `Password`

[Pic Of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVVNh.png)

Comment: Put an empty space between `*` and `from`, like `Select * from User`

Comment: I have tried that. still gives me the same error

Comment: Check David's answer

Comment: I suggestion you do not add user parameter in sql text, use C# addWidthValue parameter. Because your method allow to SQL INJECTION attack problem. https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rootturk I have been reading about SQL INJECTION issues but ill admit I don't understand yet. but thank you.

Comment: @JaredBarrett No problem, Few examples and about protection. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SQL-Injection-Attack-its-examples-and-Prevention-mechanisms-and-Techniques-in-ASPNet.aspx  and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev  and msdsn link  : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"User" is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL Server.  To use it as an identifier for a schema object, surround it with square braces:

```
SELECT * FROM [User]
```

It's generally good practice to do this with schema object identifiers anyway.  It makes them more explicit in the query.

Additionally, you are:

- directly concatenating user input as executable code, which is a SQL injection vulnerability.  Use query parameters instead.
- storing user passwords as plain text, which is ***grossly irresponsible*** to your users.  User passwords should be obscured with a one-way hash and should *never* be retrievable.

Comment: I do get that, I'm just trying to get the basics down and I'm teaching myself as i go along.. once the program works.. I will try the security parts.

Comment: @AlexK. How would you rewrite it so it is not disposing the command/connection?

Comment: Wrap the connection and command instantiation in a `using (...) {}` statement; that will take care of it for you.

Comment: are you talking about `using System.Windows.Media;` or `using System.Data.Sql;`?

Comment: I mean the using statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @JaredBarrett: No, there are two `using` constructs in C#.  The one you describe is at the top of a file, indicating a namespace to be imported to that file.  Alex is describing a "`using` block" which is a kind of syntax shorthand for a `try/finally` block to be used on any `IDisposable` object.  For example: `using (var conn = new SqlConnection()) { /* use the connection */ }`  At the end of the block, the `SqlConnection` object would be disposed automatically.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help I will read into everything and try it out. Did not know the community was so helpful <3

Answer (score 0):

Put the word User in square brackets like `[User]` because it's a defined keyword in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Some words are protected

try

```
Select * from [User] where Username.....
```